# Wrap a function in python supplying an additional boolean

Tags: python, wrapper

I'm porting some code from Perl to Python, and one of the functions I am moving does the following:

```
sub _Run($verbose, $cmd, $other_stuff...)
{
  ...
}

sub Run
{
  _Run(1, @_);
}

sub RunSilent
{
  _Run(0, @_);
}
```

so to do it Python, I naively thought I could do the following:

```
def _Run(verbose, cmd, other_stuff...)
  ...

def Run(*args)
  return _Run(True, args);

def RunSilent
  return _Run(False, args);
```

but that doesn't work, because args is passed as an array/tuple. To make it work, I did the following:

```
def _Run(verbose, cmd, other_stuff...)
  ...

def Run(*args)
  return _Run(True, ','.join(args));

def RunSilent
  return _Run(False, ','.join(args));
```

but that looks kind of ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` can be used for [passing (positional) arguments](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls) too.

```
def Run(*args):
  return _Run(True, *args)
```

Note that, with only this, you can't call the function with keyword arguments. To support them one need to include the `**` as well:

```
def Run(*args, **kwargs):
  return _Run(True, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

Actually you could declare the function as

```
def run(cmd, other_stuff, silent=False):
   ...
```

then it could be called as

```
run("foo", etc)               # Run
run("foo", etc, silent=True)  # RunSilent
```

Comment: Thanks. I did end up going with this:

  def run(cmd, other_stuff, silent=False):


Sometimes, while porting this Perl stuff, I get too literal, and don't stop and think how I would do it in Python.

Answer (score 3):

There's also functools.partial:

```
from functools import partial

Run = partial(_Run, True)
RunSilent = partial(_Run, False)
```

This will create the two functions you want. Requires python 2.5 or higher.